# Во втором контроллере получить ссылку на первый контроллер

Tags: java, javafx

Добрый день. Я новичок в Java поэтому сильно не ругайтесь. Пишу приложение которая работает с БД. Есть класс `Registrator` на основе, которого заполняется `TableView`, есть класс `TableRegistrators`, который заполняет список типа `ObservableArrayList` данными из таблицы. В этом же классе `TableRegistrators` заполняется список типа `TreeSet<Integer>` значениями из колонки `nom_reg` таблицы. Тут вроде все понятно описал думаю.

Есть два класса-контроллера `MainController` (контроллер основной формы) и `AddController` (контроллер формы, где добавляется новый элемент в таблицу).

В контроллере `MainController` есть метод `getMaxNomReg()`, который возвращает последний элемент из списка `nomRegList` (заполняется в классе `TableRegistrators`).

Теперь у меня вопрос: Как во второй контроллер `AddController` передать ссылку на первый контроллер MainController? А точнее мне нужно во втором контроллере в хранить результат, который возвращает метод getMaxNomReg(). Подскажите пожалуйста как это реализовать?

Пытался сделать через конструктор класса `AddController`, таким образом:

```
public AddController(MainController mainController ) {
    this.mainController  = mainController ;
}
```

Но выпадает ошибка `NullPointerException`. Ниже все три класса:

```
public class MainController {
    @FXML
    private TableView<Registrator> tableRegistrator;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Registrator, Integer> columnNumber;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Registrator, String> columnFIO;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Registrator, String> columnPassword;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Registrator, String> columnTimeType;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Registrator, String> columnOtd;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Registrator, String> columnPri;

    private TableRegistrators tableRegs = new TableRegistrators();
    private Stage mainStage;

    //Для модального окна ConfigStage
    private FXMLLoader fxmlAddLoader = new FXMLLoader();
    private AddController addController;
    private Parent fxmlAdd;
    private  Stage addStage;

    //Метод инициализации
    public void initialize() throws SQLException, IOException {
        fillTableRegistrators();

        columnNumber.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Registrator, Integer>("nom_reg"));
        columnFIO.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Registrator, String>("nam"));
        columnPassword.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Registrator, String>("parol"));
        columnTimeType.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Registrator, String>("slovo"));
        columnOtd.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Registrator, String>("maska"));
        columnPri.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Registrator, String>("pri"));

        addDialogLoader();

    }

    //Метод заполняет TableView tableRegistrator записями из таблицы personal
    public void fillTableRegistrators() throws SQLException, IOException {
        tableRegs.fillRegistratorsList();
        tableRegistrator.setItems(tableRegs.getRegistratorsList());
    }

    //Метод указывает подмостки для данного контроллера
    public void setMainStage(Stage mainStage) {
        this.mainStage = mainStage;
    }

    //Метод загружает окно fxmlAdd
    private void addDialogLoader() {
        try {
            fxmlAddLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("../fxml/add.fxml"));
            fxmlAdd = fxmlAddLoader.load();
            addController = fxmlAddLoader.getController();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //Метод отображает окно Add при необходимости
    private void showAddDialog() {
        if (addStage == null) {
            addStage = new Stage();
            addStage.setTitle("Добавить регистратора");
            addStage.setMaxWidth(780);
            addStage.setMaxHeight(365);
            addStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
            addStage.initOwner(mainStage);
            addStage.setResizable(false);
            addStage.setScene(new Scene(fxmlAdd));
        }
        addStage.showAndWait();
    }

    public int getMaxNomReg() {
        return tableRegs.getNomRegList().last();
    }

    public void onBtnPress(ActionEvent event) {
        //Получаем источник событий
        Object source = event.getSource();

        //Если источник не кнопка, то выходим из программы
        if (!(source instanceof Button)) {
            return;
        }

        Registrator selectedRegistrator = (Registrator) tableRegistrator.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

        Button clickedButton = (Button) source;

        switch (clickedButton.getId()) {
            case "btnAdd":
                addController.setRegistrator(new Registrator());
                showAddDialog();
                tableRegs.add(addController.getRegistrator());
                break;
        }
    }

}

public class AddController {
    private Registrator registrator;

    public void setRegistrator(Registrator registrator) {
        if (registrator == null) {
            return;
        }
        this.registrator = registrator;
    }

    public Registrator getRegistrator() {
        return registrator;
    }

    public void btnOkPress(ActionEvent event)  throws SQLException, IOException {

    }

    public void btnCancelPress(ActionEvent event) {
        Node source = (Node) event.getSource();
        Stage stage = (Stage) source.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.hide();
    }
}

public class TableRegistrators implements TableRegistratorsInterface{
    //Создаем пустой список типа ObservableList
    ObservableList<Registrator> registratorsList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    TreeSet<Integer> nomRegList = new TreeSet<>();

    //Запросом получаем из таблицы personal поочередно записи и добавляем их в список registratorsList
    public void fillRegistratorsList() throws SQLException, IOException {
        try (Connection connection = DBConnection.getConnection()) {
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            String query = "Select * from personal";
            try (ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query)) {
                while (resultSet.next()) {
                    int nom_reg = resultSet.getInt("nom_reg");
                    int id_reg = resultSet.getInt("id_reg");
                    String nam = resultSet.getString("nam");
                    String parol = resultSet.getString("parol");
                    String pri = resultSet.getString("pri");
                    String slovo = resultSet.getString("slovo");
                    String maska = resultSet.getString("maska");

                    registratorsList.add(new Registrator(nom_reg, id_reg, nam, parol, pri, slovo, maska));
                    nomRegList.add(nom_reg);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //Просто возвращаем список registratorsList
    public ObservableList<Registrator> getRegistratorsList() {
        return registratorsList;
    }

    public TreeSet<Integer> getNomRegList() {
        return nomRegList;
    }

    //Удаление регистратора
    @Override
    public void add(Registrator registrator) {
        registratorsList.add(registrator);
    }

}
```

**Обновление**

Написал так:

```
//Метод загружает окно fxmlAdd
private void addDialogLoader() {
    try {
        fxmlAddLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("../fxml/add.fxml"));
        fxmlAddLoader.setController(addController = new AddController((MainController) this));
        fxmlAdd = fxmlAddLoader.load();
        addController = fxmlAddLoader.getController();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

А в AddController так

```
private MainController mainController;

public AddController(MainController mainController) {
    this.mainController = mainController;
}
```

Можете объяснить почему сейчас заработало, а если в fxml файле прописать контроллер не сработало?

и эту строчку не до конца понял:

```
fxmlAddLoader.setController(addController = new AddController((MainController) this));
```

Comment: Почему бы вам не сделать сервис для TableRegistrators, который будет синглтоном и будет вызываться там и там?

Comment: Как понять сервис для TableRegistrators? Если шаблон имеете ввиду, то я этой темы еще не касался. Но обязательно поизучаю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как я понял, указание на класс контроллера находится в fxml описании. Если так, то можно попробовать затереть его и написать:

```
//Метод загружает окно fxmlAdd
private void addDialogLoader() {
    try {
        fxmlAddLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("../fxml/add.fxml"));
        fxmlAddLoader.setController( addController = new AddController( (MainController)this ) );
        fxmlAdd = fxmlAddLoader.load();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Обновление**

Указанный в fxml описании класс грузится с дефолтного конструктора, т.е. "`new AddController();`" или "`new AddController( null );`". Вместо этого подсовываем loader'у контроллер самостоятельно с необходимой инициализацией. Строчку можно разбить на две, если так понятней:

```
addController = new AddController((MainController) this));
fxmlAddLoader.setController(addController);
```

Comment: Это понял. Может и глупый вопрос, но все же, а почему this приводится к MainController? здесь this я так понимаю это будет ссылка на класс AddController? или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: this - это ссылка на объект из которого он был вызван, т.е. MainController. Приводить вообще не обязательно в данном случае, а сделано это для наглядности и чтобы не расписывать конструктор AddController'а

Comment: Понял, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Можно для сначала создать singleton для этого класса

```
public class TableRegistrators implements TableRegistratorsInterface{
    //Создаем пустой список типа ObservableList
    ObservableList<Registrator> registratorsList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    TreeSet<Integer> nomRegList = new TreeSet<>();

    ...

    //Удаление регистратора
    @Override
    public void add(Registrator registrator) {
        registratorsList.add(registrator);
    }

    public TableRegistrators getInstance() {
        // любимый способ получения экземпляра объекта в единичном виде. См. Singlton pattern
    }

}
```

Далее:

```
//Метод заполняет TableView tableRegistrator записями из таблицы personal
public void fillTableRegistrators() throws SQLException, IOException {
    TableRegistrators.getInstance().fillRegistratorsList();
    tableRegistrator.setItems(TableRegistrators.getInstance().getRegistratorsList());
}
```

И в AddController:

```
public void getMaxNomReg() {
    return TableRegistrators.getInstance().getNomRegList().last()
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Буду разбираться с паттернами.. Я этой темы как-то не касался пока еще..